# LWR site (Experiece Cloud) unsupportting toast events?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, experience-cloud, lwr

Does anyone have some information about Toast Events in LWR sites? In the [sample LWR site](https://github.com/trailheadapps/az-insurance), in line 76 of footerMenuItem.js developer is using a ShowToastEvent, but:

**Is this unsupported by LWR sites?**

I'm trying the same in a LWR community portal to show the user a success message but is not showing at all

Thanks in advance to anyone that may have some information about this! (***Or any workaround for this.***)

Answer (score 1):

Toast events are now supported in LWR sites in the Summer 23 release (in Beta).

Here's the release notes: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_toastcontainer.htm&release=244&type=5

And here's the documentation on the Toast Container component: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-toast-container/documentation

Answer (score 0):

It seems to not be supported.

I found a workaround that works: (Still I would appreciate if anyone has more information)
It can be found here: https://cafeforce.com/custom-toast-notification-lwc-salesforce/

Using a custom reusable toast. I found this by looking answers in this question: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000Bju8QAC